3 input videos - where vid2 follows vid1 whereas vid3 is full length - into 2 halves side-by-side video
There were two simultaneous shootings of the same event,
and there was a break in the shooting with camera1, so there are 2 videos from camera1, one following another, with a few seconds missing in-between.
Camera2 wasn't interrupted so video3 is full-length.
The task is to put a side-by-side full-length video.
There is no difference how would missing seconds be displayed on its half - it may be black or it may display the last frame from vid1 keeping it still, or whatever (although approaches to treat it are welcome).
Thanks

use -itsoffset to delay second video
ffmpeg -i "cam1killer1.mp4" \
-itsoffset 10 -i "cam1killer2.mp4" \
-i "cam2killer3.mp4" -lavfi "
color=black:1280x1000[b];
[b][0]overlay[b];
[b][1]overlay=enable='gt(t,10)'[b];
[b][2]overlay=0:500:shortest=1
" -map 2:a -c:a copy out.mp4 -y

-map 2:a will take audio from camera2
